# Javascript concatenation error or Node.js MSSQL module adding extra quote marks?

Tags: javascript, sql-server, concatenation

I am trying to send a query to SQL Server using Node.js and the MSSQL module

```
const dataSend = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        sql.connect(config).then(pool => {

            myQuery = "INSERT INTO persoane ([name], telefon) VALUES ('"+req.body.name+"','"+req.body.telefon+"')";

            resolve(pool.request().query(myQuery));
            reject('Error in dataSend');
        })
    });
```

Using SQL Server Profiler, I can see the query being sent to SQL Server as:

```
'INSERT INTO persoane ([name], telefon) VALUES (' 'John' ',' '11111111111' ')'
```

The double quotes on `VALUES` produce a error. How to write just one single quote in the final query?

Did I concatenate wrong or is something from MSSQL?

Thank you!

Comment: what do you see if you `console.log(myQuery)`

Comment: Save yourself lots of trouble, and do this correctly using parameters.

Comment: What does it actually put in your database?

Comment: a console log comes out like this:  INSERT INTO persoane ([name], telefon) VALUES ('John','11111111111') , so its ok.

Comment: @DaleK In the database there is just a error. What arrives there is : INSERT INTO persoane ([name], telefon) VALUES (''John'',''11111111111'') . Because the extra single ticks in VALUES, the query gives the error Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near 'John'.

Comment: _Did I concatenate wrong?_ Yes. As DaleK mentioned: use parameters. Read the [prepared statement](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#prepared-statement) documentation on the mssql module.